# White screen in phonegap

Tags: cordova

When loading and switching screens in applications phonegap flashing white screen. How to remove the white screen?

My config.xml

```
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<access origin="*"/>   
<content src="index.html" />

<!--
  <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
  <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0x000" />
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="100" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
  <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
-->
<plugins>
   <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</plugins>
```

My index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){navigator.splashscreen.hide();}    
</script>
</head>     
<body>
    <div id="centercol">
        <div id="center" align="center">
            <form>
                  <button class="chapters" formaction="chapters.html">chapters</button>
            </form> 
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

there will always be some time needed to render view with styles and load resources when opening app. to avoid this on switching screens, you should make the single-page app so all resources will be loaded once

Comment: This is a book of 200 pages. Very difficult  will redo everything.

Comment: its not about redoing, its about copying content to proper divs, nothing too complicated